# How to send the custom List data using intent's putStringArrayListExtra?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, bundle

I want to send the List data using putStringArrayListExtra

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MainActivityModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", result); 
         startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement Parcelable in your List and use `putParcelableArrayList`. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E))

Comment: What did you try? You need implement Parcelable on the Class you need to send, and use the method I mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom list  [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

```
intent.putExtra("CustomDataList", mCustomDataList);
```

Use it in the new Activity Like this :

```
Bundle data= getIntent().getExtras();
CustomList newList = (CustomList) data.getParcelable("CustomDataList");
```

For more on Parcelable you can refer: [How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable)

Answer (score 0):

You need that to your model implemented interface **Parcelable**. And use **putParcelableArrayListExtra** method